# Double image background moves on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, frontend

So what I'm trying to achieve is building a HTML page, that has a background moves the opposite direction from a mouse. Problem is, I wanted to create a double layer of images, a background and a foreground. The foreground image is smaller, while background image is fullwidth. Here's my code so far :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>trymoving</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
        }

        section
        {
            height:100vh;
            background:url(background-image.png);
            overflow:hidden;
        }

        .sec2 {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background:url('foreground-image.png');
        }
        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="first">
        <div class="sec2"></div>
    </section>

    <script>
        const section = document.getElementsByTagName('section')[0];

        section.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) =>{
            const moveX = (e.pageX * -1 / 40);
            const moveY = (e.pageY * -1 / 40);

            section.style.backgroundPosition = moveX + 'px ' + moveY + 'px';
        });
    
        const section2 = document.getElementsByClassName('sec2')[0];

        section2.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) =>{
            const moveX = (e.pageX * -1 / 10);
            const moveY = (e.pageY * -1 / 10);

            section2.style.backgroundPosition = moveX + 'px ' + moveY + 'px';
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

My current problem is that the foreground image is align left. I want it to right in the middle. Also, I want to make it responsive across multiple screen sizes.

Comment: Could you please provide your code in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io)? It makes it easier to test and try out for others...

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. Here's the link : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-hawking-dr94t?file=/index.html

What I want to achieve is that the bg moves slower than the fg, so it creates like the 3d effect, users can see the different layers. Also the mouseover should takeover the effect for the screen as a whole, not only when the cursor went on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs some tweaking in css, html and javascript.

**Centering the inner image**:
I centered the inner image with `display: flex` as you also tried... You applied it to the child element, but it needs to be set on the parent element

**Moving the foreground image:**
I replaced the inner `section` element with a `img` element. The background is still moved around with editing the `backgroundPosition` but the foreground image needs to be moved with editing `top` and `left` via JavaScript. For this to work you need to set `position: relative` on the foreground image.

**Adjusting the event listener**: You only need to listen to the `mousemove` event on the parent `section` element. See code below:

```html
<head>
    ...
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      #background {
        height: 100vh;
        background: url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/12oNQS9.jpg);
        overflow: hidden;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      #foreground {
        position: relative;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <section id="background">
      <img id="foreground" src="data:image/jpg;base64,/9j/..."></div>
    </section>

    <script>
      const backgroundEl = document.getElementById("background");
      const foregroundEl = document.getElementById("foreground");

      backgroundEl.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
        const moveBackgroundX = (e.pageX * -1) / 40;
        const moveBackgroundY = (e.pageY * -1) / 40;

        const moveForegroundX = (e.pageX * -1) / 10;
        const moveForegroundY = (e.pageY * -1) / 10;

        backgroundEl.style.backgroundPosition = moveBackgroundX + "px " + moveBackgroundY + "px";
        foregroundEl.style.left = moveForegroundX + "px ";
        foregroundEl.style.top = moveForegroundY + "px ";
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

I also [updated your codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-johnson-eng1c?file=/index.html)

Comment: Sir, this is EXACTLY what I wanted. You just solved my whole week's issue. Very mush thank you sir for your help. Really appreciate. Also thank you for your explanation. Learned a lot.

Comment: Hi Sir. I need another help from you. So I was trying to add another layer, but this time it is text, and it moves accordingly with the direction of my cursor. I studied and copied the style of the foreground, it seems to not work. I see that because of flex, it separates the element into different parts. I'm not sure how can I replace flex to make both foreground and text to stack up. I want the text to centered and on top of the foreground. I included my codesandbox link below;

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-wildflower-0xzr3?file=/index.html:11580-11653

Sorry for keep disturbing you.

Comment: The problem is that your `#text` is `position: absolute` and then `top` and `left` is relative to the parent container, which is `<section>`. And the size of `<section>` goes across the whole page and that's why your text ends up in the top left corner when moving your mouse. It might work to move your text with `paddingLeft` and `paddingTop` in JavaScript... But it seems you may have to learn more about the concepts of css to help you understand it better for the future. Try searching for something like "css box model" or "css positioning" or "css display"

Comment: I see. Ok thanks for your explanation sir. I will look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is exactly what you were after but this centers the background image and moves the image in the opposite direction

```
const moveX = ((e.pageX) - (window.innerWidth / 2)) / 30;
const moveY = ((e.pageY)  - (window.innerHeight / 2)) / 30;
section.style.backgroundPosition = (50 - moveX + "% ") + (50 - moveY + "%");
```